# Any way to estimate the bandwidth needed to use VNC?

Tags: video-streaming, vnc

I need to stream a software from Linux to Windows. Depending on its configuration, I'll have to stream 2,4 or 8 screens in 1080p. However i can not install VNC to try it myself (restrictions on my computer). 
Is there any way to estimate the approximate flux I will need to stream my software ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

VNC/RFB works by only sending updated regions of the frame buffer.  If nothing is changing very little (no?) bandwidth is used.

Additionally, there are several possible encodings usually supported to help reduce bandwidth.  Not all clients/servers support all the types, so two clients connected to the same session might utilize very different amounts of bandwidth.

All you can do is test it out using software that you typically run, in the way that you typically use it, and see how much bandwidth you usually use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll try that when i am able to do so. Sorry for the delay I forgot to check stack